# can't get php mail() working on Ubuntu desktop version with sendmail and postfix

Tags: ubuntu, php, sendmail

I'm running Ubuntu 9.10 LAMP and trying to do a simple email test with PHP and I'm not getting any emails sent.

```
mail("myemail@gmail.com", "eric-linux test", "test") or die("can't send mail");
```

I get no errors from PHP when running that script.

In my php.ini file is:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/lib/sendmail -t -i
```

---

```
$ sudo ps aux | grep sendmail
eric      2486  0.0  0.4   8368  2344 pts/0    T    14:52   0:00 sendmail -s “Hello world” myemail@gmail.com
eric      8747  0.0  0.3   5692  1616 pts/2    T    16:18   0:00 sendmail
eric      8749  0.0  0.3   5692  1636 pts/2    T    16:18   0:00 sendmail start
eric      9190  0.0  0.3   5692  1636 pts/2    T    19:12   0:00 sendmail start
eric      9192  0.0  0.3   5692  1616 pts/2    T    19:12   0:00 sendmail
eric      9425  0.0  0.3   5692  1620 pts/1    T    19:37   0:00 sendmail
eric      9427  0.0  0.3   6584  1636 pts/1    T    19:37   0:00 sendmail restart
eric      9429  0.0  0.3   5692  1636 pts/1    T    19:38   0:00 /usr/lib/sendmail restart
eric      9432  0.0  0.1   3040   804 pts/1    R+   19:38   0:00 grep --color=auto sendmail
```

When I run $ sendmail start  it just hangs there doing nothing.
I installed postfix also to see if it would help, but it didn't.

I tried to see port 25:

```
eric@eric-linux:~$ telnet localhost 25
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 eric-linux ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

do you really need a full mta installed? i never use sendmail and only have 1 postfix install for all my servers. in all others i use **ssmtp**. much simpler to configure and more efficient to use, if your server doesn't need to receive emails.

Answer (score 1):

try to "strace" sendmail to understand why it blocks.

try also to configure it to use a smart host (e.g. your internal network mail relay server, ask sysadmins):

```
yum|apt-get install sendmail-cf

vim /etc/mail/sendmail.mc 

define(`SMART_HOST',`smtpserver.tld')
```

or

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`localhost')    <-- to enforce sendmail to use your postfix
```

note that in this strange syntax

```
dnl define(`SMART_HOST',`smtpserver.tld')
```

is a commented line!!!  so get rid of dnl if you found on the smart_host default line

build the conf

```
m4 sendmail.mc > sendmail.cf

service sendmail restart
```

test it:

```
sendmail -s "Test" youraddr@ciao.it
```

Answer (score 0):

try the [examples in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) instead. If it works, most probably you forgot to pass additional info to mail(). Otherwise, the area to look for would be your sendmail configuration.

Comment: It seems I'm getting the emails, but they come in very slowly around 10-15 minutes later. When I run the simple mail function in PHP the page hangs there for around 30 seconds until completely finished loading. Also, I should mention, I'm using an old computer with 500MB of Ram. Do you think that could be the problem?

In my email client it shows the From address as "www-data <www-data@eric-linux>"

thanks

Comment: It looks like DNS timeouts. Check that you have your hostnames resolvable via DNS or in /etc/hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the firewall? I had been pulling my hair to fix such a problem after configuring a strict firewall blocking all input & output ports except the ones being used by daemons.